# How to remove new Notifications from banner?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to handle remote notification payloads before they’re delivered and display in notification centre?

Comment: The problem is that even if you implement some custom solution (for example delivering silent notifications and then decide in the app if you would create a local notification with the intended payload or not) the user _always_ has the last word by turning background fetch off... So if you need a 100% sure method for screening notifications, I'm afraid the answer is no.

Comment: Alladinian was talking about this method you can implement inside App Delegate `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`. It is called after notification is delivered and presented, there may even be a delay. And it's not guaranteed to be called when the user suspends your app. So there is no perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

With push notifications of default type there is no way to filter out notifications if the app is not in foreground.

The possible solution to this is to use VoIP push notifications in conjunction with PushKit.

VoIP pushes are always waking up the application, however they are not presented to the user and don't modify app badge value, so it's up to the developer to show a local notification upon the received VoIP push and to deal with app badge.

There is a technique with additional silent push that for example Facebook is using, to delete notification on iOS device when the message has been read on desktop web site. It's described here: https://www.pushwoosh.com/docs/deletable-ios-push